# ESPN Developer support, NBA array

Tags: espn

All of the sudden I'm getting TBD as a team in the NBA response, any ideas why?  Just happened recently.

[image: nba team array]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"TBD" is used when we know the scheduled dates for the next round of playoff games but do not yet know who the teams will be.

TBD stands for "To Be Determined"

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I assumed it stood for "To Be Determined", but was not sure why it would be coming thru the Teams API.  So if we query all NBA teams now, it gives us 32 teams, even though there are only 30 teams in the NBA.  Any more light you can shed on why it would be coming thru the Teams API, or is this something we will just need to know for the future around any playoff season that we will need to filter out 2 TBD "teams" when pulling a list of NBA teams?  Thanks again for the response-